# 'User' object has no attribute 'rank'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

So I have this UserProfile model which has ranking system but the problem is its keep getting some attribute error

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='default.png')
    bio = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,  unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=False)
    rating= models.IntegerField(default=200,null=True,blank=False)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="major")
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="rank")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and here is its serializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_pic = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    rank = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    major = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_profile_pic(self, obj):
        try:
            pic = obj.profile_pic.url
        except:
            pic = None
        return pic
    
    def get_rank(self,obj):
        rank = obj.rank
        serializer = RankSerializer(rank,many=False)
        return serializer.data

    def get_major(self,obj):
        major = obj.major
        serializer = MajorSerializer(major,many=False)
        return serializer.data
```

I dont know why but I am getting this User error
Can someone help me please

```
Internal Server Error: /api/questions/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\code\myWebsites\javabi\backend\question\views.py", line 32, in getQuestions
    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1882, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "F:\code\myWebsites\javabi\backend\question\serializers.py", line 67, in get_user
    return serializer.data
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\siavash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 1882, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "F:\code\myWebsites\javabi\backend\users\serializers.py", line 47, in get_rank
    rank = obj.rank
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'rank'
[23/Nov/2021 19:15:48] "GET /api/questions/ HTTP/1.1" 500 157310
```

here is all of the error stack trace
I am adding this to make sure stackoverflow be fine with all of this lines of code  some more stuff dont look at this dont waste your time please sorrry

Comment: Which line causes the error? Look at the error carefully: you have a `User` object which definitely doesn't have a attribute `rank`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the get_rank function is reason for the error

Comment: ok, that narrows it down a little, but which exact line causes the error? And how is `get_rank()` called?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice once you send a get request it will get all of the data for the user thats how it will call the get_rank function

Comment: Let me rephrase my question/request: please post the entire stack trace for the error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice here you are

Comment: Ok, that's the last 3 lines of the stack trace. What is the rest?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you :)

Comment: @amirhosseindelkhosh The error is likely in your view, I assume you pass a `User` object to your serializer which is infact a serializer for `UserProfile` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem it was in my questionSerializer which I had to make sure I am getting the userprofile obj
here is the code if you want

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Question
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_user(self,obj):
        user = obj.user.userprofile #edited this from obj.user
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user,many=False)
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: `get_user()` should be `get_user_profile()`